# Validate url for iOS start with www

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex

I want url start with www and end with any type like .com , .co etc

> example - www.example.com or any other.

I tried

```
-(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
NSString *urlRegEx =
@"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

But it works with http and https

Comment: "But it works with http and https"? Meaning what? The expression above will validate both, and you don't want https address to pass the test? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want that Url start with www and end with any domains like .com ,.co,.org,.net anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex works for all the valid url with or without http ,https ,www.

```
Regex=@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))*(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’])*)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are very powerful, but for this simple case how about two category methods.

```
@implementation NSString (SuffixTest)

- (BOOL)jc_startsWithAnyOf:(NSArray*)prefixes
{
    for (NSString *candidate in prefixes) {
        if ([self hasPrefix:candidate]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)jc_endsWithAnyOf:(NSArray *)suffixes
{
    for (NSString *candidate in suffixes) {
        if ([self hasSuffix:candidate]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}


@end
```

And then use as:

```
- (BOOL)isValidAddress:(NSString*)string
{
    return [string jc_startsWithAnyOf:@[@"http://www.", @"https://www."]] && 
        [string jc_endsWithAnyOf:@[@"com", @"org"]];
}
```

. . . a little more verbose, but at least doesn't require consulting the regular expression docs to understand the code.

Comment: +1, but if you're adding methods to Apple objects via categories, you should add a prefix to those method names to avoid conflicts. See Apple's [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html), section _"Avoid Category Method Name Clashes"_.

Comment: @DarkDust Agree, namespace clashes can be nasty to debug (actually I raised a feature request for AppCode to detect this as one of their code inspections) . . should've shown this in the answer.